# Ontotext GraphDB Repository cannot be used for queries

Tags: repository, graphdb

I am getting an error message while trying to sparql in a particular repository.
Error :

The currently selected repository cannot be used for queries due to an error:

*Page [id=7, ref=1,private=false,deprecated=false] from pso has size of 206 != 820 which is written in the index: PageIndex#244 [OPENED] ref:3 (parent=null freePages=1 privatePages=0 deprecatedPages=0 unusedPages=0)*

So I tried to recreate the repository by uploading a new RDF file, but still issue persist. Any solution? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates an inconsistency between what is written in the index (pso.index) and the actual page (pso). Is there any chance that the binary files were modified/over-written/partially merged? Under normal operation, you should never get this an error.

The only way to hide this error is to start GraphDB with: `./graphdb -Dthrow.exception.on.index.inconsistency=false`. I will recommend doing this only for dumping the repository content into an RDF file, drop the repository, and recreate it.